# Why doesn't my data sync in my controller with Angular and Mongoose?

Tags: angularjs, mongodb, mean-stack

I am working on an e-commerce site using the MEAN Stack that has user accounts.  I am trying to make it so that if someone adds products to their cart without being logged in the items are added to a cookie cart. Then if the user logs in, the cart is added to their account in the database and synced.

However, I am having an issue.  If someone adds items to their cart before being logged on, the items are indeed transferred to their cart upon logging in (they are added to the database). However, this change is not reflected until some change is made while they are logged in.

So, for example, if someone adds 5 items to their cart before logging in, and then logged in, it would show no items in their cart. Then after adding a single item to their cart, it would show 6 items.  Is there a way to avoid this?

Here is my code:

**Angular User Factory**

```
angular.module('app')
  .factory('UserFactory', function ($http, $cookieStore, $location, AuthTokenFactory) {
    var user = {};

    function login (email, password) {
      return $http.post('/api/login/login', {
        email: email,
        password: password
      }).then(function success (response) {
        AuthTokenFactory.setToken(response.data.token);
        user.currentUser = response.data.user;
        user.currentUser.show = true;
        if ($cookieStore.get('cart')) {
          $cookieStore.remove('cart');
        }
      }, function (httpError) {
        throw httpError.status + " : " + httpError.data;
      });
    }

    ...

    var user = {
      addToCart : addToCart,
      login: login,
      checkToken: checkToken,
      getUser: getUser,
      currentUser: null
    };
}
```

**Angular Product Controller**

```
angular.module('nightwalkerApp')
  .controller('AccountCtrl', function ($scope, $location, UserFactory) {
    if (!UserFactory.checkToken()) {
      $location.path('/login');
    }
    $scope.user = UserFactory.currentUser;
    $scope.logout = UserFactory.logout;
    $scope.$watch(function () {
      return UserFactory.currentUser;
    }, function () {
      $scope.user = UserFactory.currentUser;
    }, true);
  });
```

**Mongoose and Express Code**

```
  passport.use('local-login', new LocalStrategy ({
    usernameField: 'email',
    passwordField: 'password',    
    passReqToCallback: true
  },
  function (req, email, password, done) {
    Users.findOne({email: email}, function(err, user) {
      // If there are any errors, return the error before anything else
      if (err) {
          return done(err);
      }
      // Check if password is valid
      user.checkPassword(password, function(err, auth) {
        if (err) {
            return done(err);
        }
        if (!auth) {
          // An incorrect password was issued
          return done(null, false, 'Sorry, incorrect email or password'); 
        }
        // All is well
        var cart = req.cookies.cart;
        // If the user has a temporary cart, add items to real cart
        if (cart) {
          var items = JSON.parse(cart);
          user.update({$pushAll: {cart: items}}, {}, function (err, numAffected, obj) {
            return done(null, user);
          }); 
        } else {
          return done(null, user);
        } 
      });
    });
  }));
```

Comment: i would say the question lies somewhere in the implementation of `UserFactory.currentUser`. Seems like it is updated on client-side at wrong time. Is the client `user` the same as returned by mongo on server side?

Comment: About `$.watch(function`... when inner properties of the returned object are changed the $watch is not triggered. It will only be triggered when reference changes

Comment: @KirillSlatin, the issue was my use of `update` which does not return the object. Could you explain more about `$watch`? Are you saying that changes to a property of a returned item, (from a factory) are not shown - only a reference change is shown? How could I keep an item in sync as it gets updated from other controllers then?

Comment: You controllers work because you actually always replace the object itself. Take a look at this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Grety/fadu6x5c/4/). It's a bit scary because shoot an alert once you enter it. The code is extremely simple and shows that `$watch(function` fires only when Change button is pressed, which replaces the object. But field modification via `input` data-binding effects only properties of object. I.e. if you have somewhere `currentUser.cart = receivedUser.cart` your `$watch` will not trigger